# Why is the position of the select different in Chrome and FireFox?

Tags: html, css, select

```
         #allday{
            width: 175px;
            border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #666666;
            height: 22px;
        }

        <select id ="allday" style="">
            <option value = "false">FALSE</option>
            <option value = "true">TRUE</option>
        </select>
```

Does anyone know why the position of the select looks a little bit higher in Google Chrome than it does in FireFox?

Comment: hey man its because google chrome have a narrow top bar and hence causes increase in window height!

Comment: CSS RESET : http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers have pre-defined CSS values for HTML elements. If you do not specify a certain CSS rule, the browser will put in it's own for how it "thinks" it should look (if needed). For example, if you make a `<div>` element but do not specify the `display:` rule, Google Chrome will automatically set it to `display: block;`.

In any case, use inspect element and try to find where the browsers differ in the computed styles. Keep an eye out for *User-Agent Stylesheet* because those are the values inserted from the browser.

As the comments also said, a CSS RESET will also help.